# Unexpected output in Euler projects (project number 3)

Tags: python, prime-factoring

I am attempting [Project Euler Problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) with 13195 as the sample number and seem to have become stuck. Any help would be appreciate and maybe a nudge in the right direction.

This is to develop my python understanding.

```py
multiples=[]

n = 13195

for i in range(1, 13196):
  if n%i ==0:
    multiples.append(i)

for m in multiples:
  if n>m>1:
    for y in (2, m):
      if not m%y==0:
        print (m)
```

I was expecting the output to be:
5
7
13
29

But I get all the factors of 13195.

Comment: You should add the problem text as well.

Comment: Step through the logic of your program with a much smaller number.  I suggest `n=12`.  Your program will give factors 2, 3, 4, 6.  Why do you think it finds nonprime 4 when it has already found prime 2?  How could you stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the prime number calculation part of your code snippet.

Say `multiples` has the value:`[1, 5, 7, 13, 29, 35, 65]`. When the applications goes to the loop `for y in (2, m)`,

Iteration 1:
`for y in (2, 5)`
       Initially, y is `2` and it does `5%2` and prints `5` since `5%2` is not `0`. Then y will become `5` and it does `5%5` and prints nothing.

...

Iteration 7:
`for y in (2, 65)`
       Initially, y is `2` and it does `65%2` and prints `65` since `65%2` is not `0`. Then y will become `65` and it does `65%65` and prints nothing.

Since you used `for y in (2,m)` instead of `for y in range (2,m)`, the loop will always execute twice, with the values of `y=2` and `y=m`.

Basically, you do `%` operation on all the multiples with `2` and itself instead of calculating the prime. Below is an example snippet to achieve the desired output.

```
for m in multiples:
 if n>m>1:
    for y in range (2, (int)(m/2)):
      if m%y==0:
            flag=1
    if flag==0:
       print (m)
    flag=0
```

Comment: Thank you I understand all but one thing. Why is it that when I loop from 2 to m it doesnt go through all the integers between 2 and m, dividing m by each integer and only divides only by 2 and m exclusively.

Comment: Ohhh I forgot the range. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes. It was because range was missing. Hope the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sympy 
multiples=[]

n = 13195

for i in range(1, 13196):
  if n%i ==0:
    multiples.append(i)

for m in multiples:
  if n>m>1:
    if sympy.isprime(m):
        print(m)
```

the rule of python is not to create function that is already created by others. the isprime function is already created so no need for recreating it.

```
multiples=[]

n = 13195

for i in range(1, 13196):
  if n%i ==0:
    multiples.append(i)

for m in multiples:
  if n>m>1:
       for i in range(2, m//2): 

       # If num is divisible by any number between  
       # 2 and n / 2, it is not prime  
           if (m % i) == 0:
               break
       else: 
            print(m)
```

it is using else with for loop concept, if the for loop breaks, the else part will not execute, if the for loop successfully completes without breaking, the else part will be executed.

Comment: You misunderstand the point of Project Euler.  If he's going to use `sympy` he may as well do `max(sympy.ntheory.factor_.primefactors(n))` and he can solve Project Euler problem 3 with nary a thought.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski ,i have modified my solution, is it ok?

Comment: Thank you Steven Rumbalski. Jainil your second explanation is wonderful I would just like to ask if it is necessary to put the brackets at the final if where it says "if (m%i)==0".

Comment: no it is not neccessary as % has high precedence than ==

Comment: you can remove () if you want .